# Parsing a c/c++/c# file in c#

Tags: c#, c++, c

I have a c file, which has many functions in it.

I want to separate out each function and get all of them in a List(lets say, list_code), and also get name of each function in a different List(lets say, fun_code). E.g

Lets say, a c file has following code:

```
void main()
{
//some code here
}

int count (int abc)
{
///some code here
}

int adder(int def)
{
///some code here
}
```

I want the following two lists **list_code** and **fun_code** !!
The elements of **list_code** would be a list with three element, containing,

1. void main()
   {
   //some code here
   }
2. int count (int abc)
   {
   ///some code here
   }
3. int adder(int def)
   {
   ///some code here
   }

The elements of **fun_code** would be a list with three element, containing,

1. void main()
2. int count (int abc)
3. int adder(int def)

I have already written a code, which keep tracks of braces("{" and "}") and separate out full functions. But it would fail, if comments contain braces. 
Moreover i wasn't able to get the function names this way.

Kindly, let me know how can i achieve this. Any library or builtin functions would be of great help, as it would have taken care of all minor details like comments, new line and similar scenarios.

Comment: It's not C#, but Clang will probably help with this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`libclang` is probably the easiest-to-use and most mature option to parse C++.

There are several C# wrappers available - here are some results of a quick Google search:

- http://www.clangsharp.org/
- https://github.com/SimonRichards/clang-sharp

Comment: That looks like perfect solution. But i am a beginner in C#. Can you please guide me how to use code over here ! https://github.com/SimonRichards/clang-sharp

Comment: No, you need to learn the language before using it for your projects. I suggest reading [C# Step By Step](http://www.amazon.com/Microsoft-Visual-2013-Step-Developer/dp/073568183X) and then getting up-to-date with the latest C# standards.

Comment: @MuhammadNouman: if you are satisfied, do you mind accepting this answer so that the question can be marked as "solved"? Thanks.